# ¿Qué preposición se puede usar con "aumentar" o "incrementar"?

Tags: preposiciones

Cuando se aumenta 3 **por** 5 obtengo 8. Me interesa saber si "por" es correcto.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar varias preposiciones dependiendo de cómo construyas la frase.

Podrías aumentar de 3 **a** 5, o de 3 **hasta** 5. Dado el ejemplo que planteas (que me suena un poco raro al oído) yo favorecería `con` o `en`.

> Cuando se aumenta 3 **con** 5 obtengo 8
>
> Cuando se aumenta 3 **en** 5 obtengo 8

La preposición `por` suena muy forzada y rara en ese contexto. Usamos 'por` para multiplicaciones

> Tres **por** cuatro son doce

(Con el sentido de "tres **veces** cuatro") Por lo que alguien te podría decir, dado tu ejemplo, que "tres **por** cinco son quince, y no ocho" ya que podrían entender que intentas aumentar tres por cinco **veces** (cinco veces tres). Por tanto, yo no favorecería el uso de esa preposición en esa situación.

Comment: Gracias, ver el "por" hacia que me dieran ganas de que me explotara la cabeza.

Comment: También se entendería _aumentar 3 **en** 5_.

Comment: me parese que el "en" utilizado de esa manera implica una division

Answer (score 0):

Yo siempre he oído "en", y tiene sentido cuando el número deja de ser pronombre:

> aumentar **en** cinco unidades.

Al menos en el contexto científico es ésta la que se usa.

Comment: Yo creo que se puede distinguir entre "aumentar 3 en 5" que me parece significar que 3 cambia y ahora es 5. El caso en mi pregunta es diferente. Aquí se suma 5 par obtener 8.

Comment: En ese caso, para no dejar lugar a dudas, deberías optar por no escatimar en preposiciones y decir "aumentar de tres a cinco", o "desde tres hasta cinco"...

Comment: No, ese es exacto el primer caso.

Comment: Ah perdón, lo he entendido mal. "Aumentar de 3 a 5" significa convertir el 3 en 5 (el aumento es 2). "Aumentar 3 en cinco unidades" significa **añadir** 5 unidades (ahora es 8). Finalmente, "aumentar por 5" suena muy mal y da a entender que lo que quieres es multiplicar por 5 (el 3 cinco veces = 15).